# Can I call getGraphics() inside overridden paint(Graphics)?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I'm using lambda functions with custom functional interfaces to shorten some nested loops that occur regularly in my code. As I don't want to add additional parameters to my expressions and end with something like *this* all over my code:

`doubleLoop((int i, int j, Graphics graphics) -> drawHexagonRandomColor(i, j, graphics), g);`

can I call `getGraphics()` to get the graphics context inside my `@Override public void paint(Graphics g) {...}` (instead of using the parameter `g`) without unexpected/negative side-effects?

Comment: As a fairly inexperienced user, I'd appreciate a comment following any negative feedback, so that I'd know how to improve my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I call getGraphics() inside my @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {...} without unexpected/negative side-effects?

What's the point?  `paint` already has a reference to `Graphics`.

What happens when someone else wants to use your code?  Will they know NOT to call these methods outside of the context of the paint routine?

Are there consequences?  Not the way you're intending to use it, but what happens if you want to change to using a `BufferedStrategy` instead of the standard painting routine?  What happens if you want to paint the results to a `BufferedImage` instead?

You've build in an inflexible solution which has it's own dangerous side effects.  For the preserved benefit (of not having one additional parameter), you lose a lot of flexibility, reuse and self documentation.

> No one else will use my code

That's only part of the point, you should always challenge yourself to assume that someone else will use your code, it makes you a better developer, stops you from taking shortcuts or cutting corners.

`getGraphics` is just a bad idea generally and should be avoided wherever possible

Comment: A quick question for further research: How would it conflict with `BufferedStrategy`? I assume I'll have some flickering issues to resolve at a future point. Thank you for general advices, they help a lot.

Comment: `BufferedStrategy` doesn't use the same painting process as say something like a Swing component (`JPanel` for example), it has it's own `Graphics` context, which you have to get from it, so if you were using `getGraphics` internally, they you'd not be able to use ... and no, you shouldn't even think about overriding `getGraphics` either.  Swing is double buffered, but uses a passive rendering engine, updating only when it needs to, `BufferedStrategy` gives you direct control (ie direct painting) over the painting process